# how to using swift delegate with cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridge

this is my swift code:

```
import UIKit

protocol ViewDelegate {
    func ViewClicked()
}

class DetailView: NSObject {
    class func display(viewName: String){

    }
    class func show(tmpDelegate: ViewDelegate?){

    }
    class func showWith2params(viewName: String,tmpDelegate: ViewDelegate?){

    }
}
```

this is part of my project-Swift.h generated by XCode7.0.1:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC15testClassMethod10DetailView")
@interface DetailView : NSObject
+ (void)display:(NSString * __nonnull)viewName;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

what should i do to use my swift class function with custom delegate parameter?

Comment: i think you need to add @objc before the protocol and the class and every function that needs to be used for the objc classes

Comment: @BjörnRo Ro i've tried ,but it didnt work.but thanks

Comment: also the func declaration in the protocol?

Comment: @BjörnRo it works.thanks! the key is to add `@objc` before the protocol declaration

Comment: cool, than i will write this as an anweser ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making functions / classes visible in Objective see you need to make sure that u set @objc to the relevant point.

Also in Protocol declarations :)